# A question on "que" which could be a conjunction or relative pronoun

Tags: conjonctions, pronoms-relatifs

The question is on this sentence from La porte étroite by André Gide.  The name of the character narrating it is Jerome.

> Il me plaisait que cette habitude quasi monacale me préservât d’un monde qui, du reste, m’attirait peu et qu’il m’eût suffi qu’Alissa pût craindre pour m’apparaître haïssable aussitôt.

**Question**

Which is the correct way to parse it?

Parsing A:

> Il me plaisait [1A] **que** cette habitude quasi monacale me préservât d’un monde qui, du reste, m’attirait peu et [2] **qu**’il m’eût suffi qu’Alissa pût craindre pour m’apparaître haïssable aussitôt.

By this parsing, there are two things that pleased Jerome, [1A] and [2].  But *craindre* does not have an object and therefore must be an intransitive verb.

Parsing B:

> Il me plaisait que cette habitude quasi monacale me préservât d’un monde  [1B] **qui**, du reste, m’attirait peu et [2] **qu**’il m’eût suffi qu’Alissa pût craindre pour m’apparaître haïssable aussitôt.

By this parsing, the *monde* is characterized in two ways, [1B] and [2].  I believe *qu* (in *qu'il*) would now be a relative pronoun referring back to *monde*, which is the object of *craindre*

**Background**

This is the context from which the sentence was lifted:

> Et sa voix en me disant cela était à la fois calme et triste ; mais le sourire qui l’illuminait restait si sereinement beau que je prenais honte de mes craintes et de mes protestations ; il me semblait alors que d’elles seules vînt cet arrière-son de tristesse que je sentais au fond de sa voix. Sans aucune transition, je commençai à parler de mes projets, de mes études et de cette nouvelle forme de vie de laquelle je me promettais tant de profit. L’École normale n’était pas alors ce qu’elle est devenue depuis peu ; une discipline assez rigoureuse ne pesait qu’aux esprits indolents ou rétifs ; elle favorisait l’effort d’une volonté studieuse. Il me plaisait que cette habitude quasi monacale me préservât d’un monde qui, du reste, m’attirait peu et qu’il m’eût suffi qu’Alissa pût craindre pour m’apparaître haïssable aussitôt. Miss Ashburton gardait à Paris l’appartement qu’elle occupait d’abord avec ma mère. Ne connaissant guère qu’elle à Paris, Abel et moi passerions quelques heures de chaque dimanche auprès d’elle ; chaque dimanche j’écrirais à Alissa et ne lui laisserais rien ignorer de ma vie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get it at the first reading as it's a complicated sentence, but I'm pretty sure Parsing B is correct.

Here's why : the  *qu* of "*qu'il m'eût suffi ...*" refers to *un monde* : "*Un monde qu'il m'eût suffi qu'Allissa put craindre ...*".

"Craindre" means to fear -, to be afraid of -, and cannot be used alone. With parsing A, it doesn't refer to anything.

> Il me plaisait (...) qu’il m’eût suffi qu’Alissa pût *craindre* pour m’apparaître haïssable aussitôt.

*Craindre quoi ?*

With the second parsing, both *qui/qu* refer to *un monde*.

> A world **[1B]** that didn't attract me much, and **[2]** that the sole fact that Alissa could fear it was enough to make it loathsome ("hatable") to me.

The translation is a little clumsy but the meaning is there. I hope that's clear !

Comment: Thanks! Is the French sentence a natural sounding one? Or is the construction not problematic at all? I do see that it makes perfect grammatical sense, but you would never write English that way.

Comment: It's practically poetry at this point. It's a style you see almost only in books, with very elaborate sentences that make you say "damn, this is good literature".